# Read Java encoded byte array in javascript

Tags: javascript, rest

I have a REST API in java to return byte array with long,short and byte values.

```
byte[] x = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11}

 b1 to b8 represent timestamp t1
 b9 and b10 represent short value s1
 b11 represent byte value
```

This byte array generate using `ByteBuffer` in java. API client written in javascript and I need to get values t1,s1 and b11 values.

I search to find a way and try with `ArrayBuffer` in javascript. But it doesn't solve my problem.

Please provide a proper example for this.

Comment: Can you also provide a proper example with real values of b1, b2......b11, the value you get in client side with a console log?

Comment: I don't follow proper method I think. It may not helpful. There are different length integers(byte, short, long). If I can find proper example for Java encoded byte steam decode form javascript it may helpful to me.